# How do you say "It was added a language menu."?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I would like to know how I should say "It was added a language menu" I know that 语言菜单 its language menu, but what about the verb? and the person? How I can make a sentences like this one? Thanks (:

Comment: (1) Something was added TO a language menu or (2) a language menu was added to something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `已添加到语言菜单`, which means `(It) was added to language menu`.